# Index.html file CSS loading error

Tags: html, css

I just pushed a website live, and it's only loading "raw HTML." I've been troubleshooting on this for a few hours, and can't seem to work out why.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://www.example.com/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "only loading raw HTML"?

Comment: Share your folder structure to check file path

Comment: What do console and Network Traffic say

Comment: Might be the file path add `../` to start of the path might solve the problem. Ex: `../css/freelancer.min.css`

Comment: Seems like content type rendered is `plain/text` rather than `text/html`

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right, the problem is that CSS files are residing in different folders. It is an advisable practice to create a CSS folder in the root of your site containing all the CSS files, something like that:

[image]

Then you just need to slightly modify your `link` elements in the header:

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And so you could keep adding more CSS files if needed.

I hope it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the location of you css

if you put it in separate folder, you might want to use something like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../min/freelancer.min.css">
```

if its just in the same folder as your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="freelancer.min.css">
```

now if you put in a separate folder with you index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="min/freelancer.min.css">
```

just take note that "../" makes you go back one folder from the current location of your index

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I had to combine all of the files into .index.html

Answer (score -3):

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/freelancer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Type is required please check with type.

Comment: type is not required.